# Backbone.js - How do load list or individual items from JSON on different routes?

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have just started working with Backbone.js by creating a simple portfolio site for myself. There is not much functionality at the moment but I hope to add more & more as I become familiar with the library. I am using json to populate the data for the site which either lists all my portfolio items or displays one of them depending on the route. I have the list of portfolio items working/showing but am struggling to just show one item for a specific route (/#projects/2 for example), this is where I need help.

I have tried to keep everything as simple as possible while I start learning Backbone & have seen the various Boilerplates & tutorials, none of which helped me hugely.

At these routes, I would like this to happen:

1. / - list of portfolio items
2. /#projects - list of portfolio items
3. /#projects/3 - one portfolio item

I have put my attempt into JSbin but it is not working because I don't know how to load the json properly...

- http://jsbin.com/asezul/6/edit to edit
- http://jsbin.com/asezul/6/ to view

I am certain my problem arises because I am loading all items into the collection rather than the model. Is that right?

1. **How can I make this work?**
2. **How can I improve this?**

**[EDIT --------------------]**

**After Peter's very kind help below, I am still in need of assistance. He said:**

> A view displays 1 model, a collection view displays a list of views,
>   one per model.

**So, how do I create a View to display one item from the json data & then create the collection view to display all of them? The reason I ask is because I can return all them without much of a problem but returning a single item is proving quite tricky..**

**I updated my code example too: http://jsbin.com/asezul/8/edit**

**[---------------------EDIT]**

Please let me know if you need more information, I am new to Backbone & may have missed an important part that would help to answer my questions.

Here's some code excerpts but I suggest viewing the code in JSbin:

**The model:**

```
SITE.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this, this.attributes.name);
    }
});
```

**The collection:**

```
SITE.Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SITE.Project,
    url: 'content.json',
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.portfolio;
    }
});
```

**A view:**

```
SITE.ProjectsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#main',
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        // create a collection
        this.collection = new SITE.Projects();
        // Fetch the collection and call render() method
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },
    template: SITE.helpers.template('project-list'),
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({ projects: this.collection.toJSON() }));
    }
});
```

**The router:**

```
SITE.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.el = $('#main');
    },
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "projects": "projects",
        "projects/:id": "project"
    },

    // Homepage / List of projects
    index: function() {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectsView();
    },

    // List of projects
    projects: function() {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectsView();
    },

    // Individual Project
    project: function(id) {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectView();
        console.log("You are trying to reach project " + id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So your data isn't really dynamic, so you can cheat a little bit compared to a dynamic application where the projects collection would be under constant change. I would just load the projects collection once at app startup and from there use the loaded collection and models within for the rest of your pages.

```
SITE.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        //Router's don't have a this.el
        //this.el = $('#main');
        this.projects = new SITE.Projects();
    },
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "projects": "projects",
        "projects/:id": "project"
    },

    // Homepage / List of projects
    index: function() {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectsView({collection: this.projects});
        if (this.projects.isEmpty()) {
            this.projects.fetch({success: function () {
                view.render();
            }});
        } else {
            view.render();
        }
    },

    // List of projects
    projects: function() {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectsView({collection: this.projects}).render();
    },

    // Individual Project
    project: function(id) {
        var view = new SITE.ProjectView({model: this.projects.get(id)}).render();
    }
});
```

Then keep your views simpler/dumber. Views should accept their models/collections in the options argument of the constructor/initialize. Give that a try and see if you can make it work. Your code otherwise looks like you should be able to make the corresponding view code changes on your own, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: No, at the moment, my data is not dynamic. Am I supposed to modify my models or collections? because using your code the 'root' route & '/#projects' route work as expected but not '/#projects/2' route..

Comment: You should make a `ProjectView` (singular) to just view a single project. This would be the typical backbone pattern. A view displays 1 model, a collection view displays a list of views, one per model. However, you could also keep using just your `ProjectsView` but pass it a collection containing only a single project model.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I'm sorry I still don't get it. Have you seen my jsbin example? Could you modify that to illustrate what you mean? I updated my jsbin to include your original answer: http://jsbin.com/asezul/8/edit

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my threshold for a stackoverflow answer. Backbone is extremely well documented and there are dozens of high-quality beginner examples and tutorials out there. If you hit a specific stumbling block, ask on stackoverflow, but if you don't understand how to put your project together, spend more time with the tutorials and documentation.